# Inequality in euclidean $k$-space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

Suppose that $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^k$, prove that $\|\textbf{x}\cdot\textbf{y}\| \leq \|\textbf{x}\|\|\textbf{y}\|$. 
Here $\|\textbf{x}\|$ denotes the norm of $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^k$.

I've tried to solve this directly by expanding both sides. It boils down to compare $(x_1y_1+\cdots+x_ky_k)\cdot(x_1y_1+\cdots+x_ky_k)$ to $(x_1^2 + \cdots + x_k^2)(y_1^2+\cdots+y_k^2)$. But I'm stuck on this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality with a standard proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint, look at the following equality for two vectors in $\Bbb R^n$:
\begin{align}
\vec v\cdot \vec u&=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i u_i\\
=&\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n\left( u_i^2 + v_i^2 - \left(u_i^2+v_i^2-2u_iv_i\right)\right)\\
=&\frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n \left(u_i^2+v_i^2-2u_iv_i\right)\right)\\
=&\frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n (u_i-v_i)^2\right)\\
=& \frac{1}{2}\left(\|\vec u\|^2 + \|\vec v\|^2 - \|\vec u-\vec v\|^2\right)\\
=& \|\vec u\|\|\vec v\|\cos \theta
\end{align}

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It is the Cauchy Schwarz inequality, one way to show it is assuming

$$<\frac {x}{||x||},\frac{y}{||y||}> \ = \ <a,b> \ = \sum a_ib_i \ \leq \ 1$$

and then using the fact that $$a_i b_i \leq \frac {1}{2}(a_i^2+b_i^2)$$ and $$\sum a_i^2 = \sum b_i^2\ = \ 1$$